# what are scripting languages?

Tags: programming-languages, scripting-language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is a language considered a scripting language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101055/when-is-a-language-considered-a-scripting-language)

What languages are scripting languages?? Couldn't we write scripting languages as a stand alone??

Answer (score 1):

> A scripting language, script language
>   or extension language is a programming
>   language that allows control of one or
>   more software applications. "Scripts"
>   are distinct from the core code of the
>   application, as they are usually
>   written in a different language and
>   are often created or at least modified
>   by the end-user. Scripts are often
>   interpreted from source code or
>   bytecode, whereas application software
>   is typically first compiled to a
>   native machine code or to an
>   intermediate code.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)

There is PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. More [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_category#Scripting_languages).

Scripts are ran by an interpreter, so there must be an interpreter in the Operating System for the script to run.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a scripting language is a language that is interpreted rather than compiled.