# PHP script language or programming language?

Tags: php, definition

I never understood why PHP called "scripting language" rather than "programming language".

Is me introducing myself as "PHP programmer" is wrong I should be "PHP scripter"?

What definition of programing language and scripting language?

PHP can have complicated programs done and compiled into .exe files to run on windows.

Comment: Scripting languages are programming languages.

Comment: calling yourself Php scripter or programmer, is not what matters. what matters is can you make use of the language? and do you understand what you are doing?

Comment: You should ask, what's a script and what's a program and then you find out that PHP is, at least today, clearly a programming language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is a language considered a scripting language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101055/when-is-a-language-considered-a-scripting-language)

Answer (score 9):

Usually a language is called a scripting language if it's not compiled. But these days it doesn't matter anymore - PHP programmer is probably the more accurate term.
It's also matters what are you doing with the language. Even people who write in language that have 'script' in its name Java Script are called programmers as soon as they start doing something more advanced than simple DOM manipulations with jquery.

The only people I've lately heard that refer to them selves as scripters are bash-scripters :)

Comment: nice i like that explanation, guess i am programmer after all