# Unreal Engine 4 code only

Tags: c++, scripting, unreal-engine4

I am currently getting my feet wet with Unreal Engine 4. All of the beginner tutorials I have found so far do most of their work inside the unreal editor and use C++ only for extending all of the stuff that unreal auto-generates. I would like to get a deeper understanding of how to use mainly (or if possible only) C++ to program Unreal. What I am aiming for at this point is, setting up a simple scene entirely from code.

Can anyone suggest good resources?

EDIT: So after getting familiar with the general concepts of the Unreal engine a bit more, I am realizing that most of the game development is done by visual scripting using Blueprint. Is there any way to hook up a scripting language to the Unreal architecture to either replace or integrate into Blueprint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's kind of trivial, but there is a page in the documentation:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Gameplay/ClassCreation/CodeOnly/index.html

EDIT: Also see:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Introduction/index.html

EDIT 2: Some scripting languages for Unreal Engine

- C# (project stopped, only compatible up to UE 4.5): https://mono-ue.github.io/
- JavaScript: https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?254-Linking-V8-(JavaScript)-to-UE4
- SookumSkript: http://skookumscript.com/unreal/

Epic "only" supports BluePrint as a (visual) scripting language, all other implementations a provided by the community (with some help of Epic Staff).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have already come across this page. It points into the right direction, but is not exactly what I am looking for. It feels like there are a lot of ways to extend the components Unreal offers you to build your application. You then use these components, drag & drop them inside the editor and then Unreal auto-generates a bunch of code, that actually makes it all run. Rather then doing that, I would like to setup and configure as much of the application inside code as possible.

Comment: I searched a bit, but the only other link I could find was this ("migrate" a non-C++ project into a C++ project): https://wiki.unrealengine.com/How_to_Convert_a_BP/Content_Project_to_a_C%2B%2B_Project_in_8_Steps
What do you count as a scripting language (does C++ count)?

Comment: C++ is not a scripting language. [Scripting languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101055/when-is-a-language-considered-a-scripting-language) are written for runtime environments and need only be interpreted, rather then being compiled for execution.
I have for instance previously used Python to script application setups for VR engines. In Unreal you use Blueprint to script their Game engine. I am searching for a way to get away from visual scripting, in order to integrate non visual scripts for setting up applications in Unreal.

Comment: Added some examples of script language implementations to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, your latest edit is exactly what I am looking for.