# what is the difference between server side scripting and server side programming?

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, server, serverside-javascript

I was reading about **Node.js** and it is given that node.js is used for server side scripting.

I work on **ASP.Net** and **MVC** where we have controllers/classes on server side on which we write our code. So my point here is what exactly is server side scripting language and how is it difference from server side programming? I'm confused between both. Please provide an example if possible.

Comment: Here you can find the answer :- 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253545/scripting-language-vs-programming-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple:
Programming means writing human-like code which provides some functionality and then compiling this code to machine code or to lower code (ex. IL). Program needs to be written first, then compiled and then you can run it.
On the other side, scripting is writing code, which is supposed to run in program/interpreter/engine. Javascript (NodeJS), bash script, perl, python, ... these all are scripting languages because they don't need to be compiled, just called by interpreter.
Server side scripting is simply writing scripts for programs, which are evaluated on the server and doesn't need to be compiled.
ASP .NET is translated (compiled) into IL so that means it is server-side programming. If you have any other questions, I'll be happy to answer you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. So it means instead of writing my c# code i have to work with javascript at serverside? Though i understood the meaning but trying to figure out what's the use and how will we use it?(Node.js)

Comment: Yes, you are writing pure javascript on the server side and that is evaluated by V8 JS engine under the hood of nodejs. nodejs is stateful, fast and efficient. I suggest you to check out some tutorials and try it by yourself.