# Programming and scripting languages

Tags: html, programming-languages, scripting-language

What is the difference between a programming language and a scripting language? Why HTML  is neither a programming language nor a scripting language?

If the difference is only without compilation? Then what is the advantages of having scripting language that is without compilation?

Comment: Difference between a programming language and a scripting language is already covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253545/scripting-language-vs-programming-language)

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the 2nd part of your question..
"Why HTML is neither a programming language nor a scripting language?"

HTML is a **markup** language.
It encapsulates data within tags for the browser to read and interpret web page content.
It just defines the purpose of the data on the webpage.

It however does not have any of the below properties of a programming language(to name a few)..
* It has no programming/functional logic
* It does not understand any conditional statements.
* It cannot evaluate expressions and do computation (like for eg: the sum of 2 numbers)

To summarize,
HTML => defines structure of the web page
CSS => defines the style
Javascript => provides scripting support on the web page

Answer (score -1):

HTML a mark up language
programing language is used for computing data on server side example: php,asp,jsp etc
scripting language computes on clients machine example javascript

at the end whatever browser renders in markup language ie HTML