# Is CAPL a scripting language or a programming language?

Tags: scripting, capl

I'm new to Can Access Programing Language. In some documents CAPL is described as script. Can anyone explain, why it is referred to as script?
Is it programming or scripting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253545/scripting-language-vs-programming-language) the difference between a scripting language and a programming language is basically that you need a explicit compilation step.

So CAPL is indeed a programming language, since all CAPL programs need to be compiled before they can be executed during measurement. You have a Compiler menu in the CAPL Browser and you get a "Compilation failed" error when you have syntax errors.

The reason why CAPL may sometimes be reffered to as a scripting language, is that the source code is compiled every time you hit the "Start Measurement" button automatically by CANoe. And it is also quite fast, so you might not even notice it is happening.

Comment: Please read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and consider accepting the answer, if it was useful to you. (The grey check arrow that turns green when you click it)