# Maya how to use C++

Tags: c++, plugins, maya

I feel that I must be stupid, or missing something, but I can't find, even after hours on the web, how to install, use, load, (whatever it is you need to do) a cpp file to maya.

I want to export my model as a .raw file, and I found on the internet the c++ solution to do this. I then discovered that it already existed in a plug-ins folder with maya on my computer. But never the less, I can't export as a raw, and I have no idea how ti implement this polyRawExport.cpp script. I am using a Mac.

Comment: Explanations here, accepted answer: [Difference between scripting and programming languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253545/scripting-language-vs-programming-language)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build .so file from c++ file using xcode or what ever compiler you like. http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html?url=files/Setting_up_your_build_environment_Mac_OS_X_environment.htm,topicNumber=d30e5169 which explaining how to do

Comment: actually the extension is .bundle on OSX vs .so which is for Linux. Now for well verse Xcode programmer, whilst we use .bundle on OSX, this is a .so renamed .bundle, so not a true bundle.