# Difference between Unix/cmd scripts and python scripts

Tags: scripting

I was doing some research on scripts and learning about bash scripts. I recently found out that you can also write scripts in other languages like python. I'm curious what the advantages and disadvantages are of writing scripts in the native OS language (I guess that's what you'd call it) and another scripting language like python.

Comment: I changed my question. It is no longer a duplicate. I apologize for the initial duplicate.

Comment: This is both too broad and opinion based. There are many differences and what is considered an advantage is a disadvantage to someone else, and vice versa. Please do study our [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A script or scripting language is a computer language with a series of commands within a file that is capable of being executed without being compiled. Good examples of server side scripting languages include Perl, PHP, and Python. The best example of a client side scripting language is JavaScript.

From http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/script.htm

You can read:

[Scripting Language vs Programming Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253545/scripting-language-vs-programming-language)

http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/definition/script