# VB scripting without autocomplete

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a short script for some data analysis (kind of software automation). - in vb 
The program I have to use for that is so old that the autocomplete feature isnt working ... is it possible to somehow list all parameters from a disticnt method? - their reference just states 'The parameters for this algorithm are specified in the method' (which is very helpful)

[Edit]
It's a built-in editor of the Bruker Daltonics automation software; which uses VBA

Comment: VBA? VBScript? VB6? VB.NET?

Comment: What program are you using then?? Also VB.NET is about coding, not scripting. [There's a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253545/scripting-language-vs-programming-language) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl-alt-J. That brings up the Object Explorer in most flavors of VB.

Also try right-clicking and see if there is a "Go to Definition" option.