# Why is this lookup function slow?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following UDF function to return True if a cell value is found in a specified range and return False otherwise:

```
Function find_in_range(value_to_find As Variant, lookup_range As Range) As Boolean

For Each cell In lookup_range.Cells.SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    If cell.Value = value_to_find Then
        find_in_range = True
        Exit For
    Else
        find_in_range = False
    End If
Next cell

End Function
```

However, it is considerably slower than let's say VLOOKUP.

Why is that so? Is there a way to make it faster? What magic is used to make VLOOKUP search faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to make it a bit faster:

```
Public Function findInRange(valueToFind As Variant, lookupRange As Range) As Boolean
    findInRange = Not IsError(Application.Match(valueToFind, lookupRange, 0))
End Function
```

*What magic is used to make VLOOKUP search faster?*

- Programming in C

Answer (score 1):

Built in functions are in most cases (I would even say all) faster than VBA can ever be. They are already compiled and native code.

They can also use multi-threading where VBA can not. All such effects make them acting a lot faster. Also you won't want to re-invent the wheel. So I suggest to use built in functions where ever possible.

Comment: Code written in VBA is compiled[4] to Microsoft P-Code (packed code), a proprietary intermediate language, ... from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications

Comment: @Vityata What I meant to say there, is that VBA needs to be compiled before you can run it, which takes time. Builtin functions don't need that extra compiling time.

Comment: @PEH - VBA is actually compiled on the moment you write it on the VBA Editor. Still, the built-in functions are uncomparable in speed. See the last comments below this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17253557/5448626

Comment: @Vityata Nice, good to know. Now that explains why you actually get a *compile error* on every single line immediate after typing and not when trying to execute the code. Makes totally sense now. Thanks for clarifying, always a pleasure.

Comment: @PEH - you are welcome. Actually, this is one of the reasons why I personally consider that VBA to be hugely underestimated.

Comment: @Vityata: I completely agree!. I think VBA (or Excel for that matter) is one of the most underrated `"tools"` out there. Also completely agree.. VBA is NOT a scripting language by any stretch of the imagination.. some interesting takes on languages in that thread though :)

Comment: @Zac - The underrating of VBA is something that everyone from the VBA world si used to. However, that thread was once used against me to show that VBA is a scripting language. I was speechless for a minute and I have tried to edit the thread later. The edit was not accepted anyway.

Comment: @Vityata: I don't want to start a conversation on this question because we could go on for hours.. but good on you for standing your ground! loved it!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you absolutely insist on poly-filling *(in a non-literal sense)*, excel already has inbuilt function `Find` that returns the `Range` if found, or `Nothing` if not

You could further modify this, into a function that evaluates into a  `Boolean`

```
Option Explicit
Function isFound(ByVal value_to_find As String, ByVal in_range as Range) As Boolean

 If in_range.Find(value_to_find, lookin:= xlValues) Is Nothing Then
    isFound = False
 Else
    isFound = True
 End If

End Function
```

Returns `true` if value can be found in range, otherwise returns `false`

---

*In general, if you can do something **without a loop it usually means it's  faster***