# always returning 466750944 in c++ calculations script

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
multiplication() {
  int x;
  int y;
  int sum;
  sum = y * x;

  cout << "multiplication" << endl;
  cout << "enter first number for multiplication: ";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "enter second number for multiplication: ";
  cin >> y;
  cout << "your product is: " << sum <<endl;
  return 0;
}
void division (){
  cout << "division" << endl;

}
void addition (){
  int y;
  int x;
  int sum = x * y;
  cin >> x;
  cin >> y;
  cout << sum;
}
void subtraction (){

}

int main()
{cout << "enter 1 for multiplication, enter 2 for division, enter 3 for addition, and enter 4 for subtraction"<<endl;
  int math;
  cin >> math;
  switch(math){

    case 1:
      multiplication();
      break;
    case 2:
      division();

    default:
      cout << "it dont work ooga booga"<<endl;
      break;
    case 3:
      addition ();
      break;
    case 4:
      subtraction();}
  return 0;
}
```

this is the script i am trying to run, im running in code::blocks if something is wrong that would cause it to always return 466750944 please tell me so i could work more on this, this may be my a problem with codeblocks if someone could also run this script in codeblocks or another ide and post their results it would be very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: `multiplication() {` is a syntax error in C++.

Comment: Always turn compiler warnings as strict as you can; that will catch all sorts of problems including this one.

Comment: `int sum = x * y`  does not declare a relationship. It's a statement that executes when it's encountered, and the resulting *value* is assigned to `sum`. Afterwards, `sum` has no knowledge of `x` or `y` and is independent of them. Changing `x` or `y` after the assignment will not change the value of `sum`.

Comment: Terminology note: [Scripting Language vs Programming Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253545/scripting-language-vs-programming-language)

Answer (score 6):

When you say `sum = x * y` that is evaluated at the point of definition, it's not a formula as in math where later on it's evaluated when rendered.

When the `sum = x * y` statement is executed, `x` and `y` are not initialized so the value of `sum` is basically garbage.

To see this behaviour in action, step through your code in a debugger and look at the values of `x`, `y` and `sum`.

Either move that to *after* `x` and `y` are properly defined, or move it to a function, like:

```
int sum(int x, int y) {
  return x * y;
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Added accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.